# Why aren't quotation marks necessary in Play framework controller?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

This works:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(<h1>hello world</h1>)
  }
}
```

But I would have expected to need to write `Ok("<h1>hello world</h1")`, using quotation marks.  Why isn't this necessary (from a Scala POV)?

Comment: Does this return an XML or an HTML content type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scala supports XML literals as a first-class part of the language: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131. This is built in to the language and the choice of framework is irrelevant.